# How to display list of processes sorted in reverse order for a bash, tsch, ksh shell in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, ksh, pid

Was wondering if someone could help me with this... I want to display a list of running processes sorted in reverse order. The reverse order is to be based on process identification value - PID.

I was also wondering does it matter for the processes to be displayed in a certain shell? do I have to include something specific in the line of code or merely just change shells. I want to do this for both tsch and bash.

I have looked up the commands but I am not sure how to bring it together. See below:

```
ps = is the command that shows information about processes running in memory
-p = by process ID
r = running processes
sorting method?
```

Not sure how to bring it together.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Something like `ps | sort`? Also, `ps -p` doesn't work in `zsh`.

Comment: @blender ps is an external command. It's options may change depending on OS, but not on different shells for the same system.

Comment: @jordanm: My bad, I thought it was a builtin and that `-p` was a bash-specific switch.

Comment: @Blender either way, it's not what he wants since -p only selects pids provided as args, not all pids.

Comment: @blender can you walk me through it pleasE?

Comment: I am only looking for processes that are running at the present moment

Comment: or @jordanm walkthrough would be appreciated

Comment: `ps` only shows currently running processes, it has no way of knowing about processes that I have ran and completed in the past.

Answer (score 3):

This will do it:

```
ps aux | sort -k2 -rn
```

The `ps` command varies depending on OS. I can confirm the above will work in Linux and FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1):

ps has it's own sort on linux, This is how I use it:

```
ps -eo pid,user,rss,vsz,pmem,comm,lstart --sort rss
```

In your case

```
ps aux --sort pid
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash the following command will do it:

```
~$ ps aux --sort -pid | less
```

Normal (descending) order is achieved by specifying `--sort pid` or `--sort +pid`. The latter doesn't make much sense though.